# Unable to start flight recorder via JMC 6 within eclipse oxygen (4.7)

Tags: java, eclipse, jmc

I have an error I don't understand. If I try to to use JFR using the JMC eclipse plugin it fails with the exception

```
com.oracle.jmc.rjmx.services.jfr.FlightRecorderException: Could not start the recording!
    at com.oracle.jmc.rjmx.services.jfr.internal.FlightRecorderServiceV1.start(FlightRecorderServiceV1.java:149)
    at com.oracle.jmc.flightrecorder.controlpanel.ui.jobs.StartRecordingJob.run(StartRecordingJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException: recording.jfr (Access denied)
    at com.oracle.jmc.rjmx.services.jfr.internal.FlightRecorderCommunicationHelperV1.invokeOperation(FlightRecorderCommunicationHelperV1.java:62)
    at com.oracle.jmc.rjmx.services.jfr.internal.FlightRecorderServiceV1.start(FlightRecorderServiceV1.java:137)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: javax.management.MBeanException: javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException: recording.jfr (Access denied)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.unwrapInvocationTargetException(MBeanIntrospector.java:313)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:239)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
    at javax.management.StandardMBean.invoke(StandardMBean.java:405)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:361)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:283)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:260)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.PRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_Stub.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.invoke(RMIConnector.java:1020)
    at com.oracle.jmc.rjmx.internal.MCMBeanServerConnection.invoke(MCMBeanServerConnection.java:224)
    at com.oracle.jmc.rjmx.ConnectionToolkit.invokeOperation(ConnectionToolkit.java:152)
    at com.oracle.jmc.rjmx.services.jfr.internal.FlightRecorderCommunicationHelperV1.invokeJfrOperation(FlightRecorderCommunicationHelperV1.java:69)
    at com.oracle.jmc.rjmx.services.jfr.internal.FlightRecorderCommunicationHelperV1.invokeOperation(FlightRecorderCommunicationHelperV1.java:56)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException: recording.jfr (Access denied)
    at oracle.jrockit.jfr.FlightRecorder.setRecordingOptions(FlightRecorder.java:221)
    at oracle.jrockit.jfr.FlightRecorder.setRecordingOptions(FlightRecorder.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
    at javax.management.StandardMBean.invoke(StandardMBean.java:405)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:361)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: recording.jfr (Access denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
    at oracle.jrockit.jfr.Recording.setDestination(Recording.java:464)
    at oracle.jrockit.jfr.Recording.setOptions(Recording.java:481)
    at oracle.jrockit.jfr.FlightRecorder.setRecordingOptions(FlightRecorder.java:219)
    ... 39 more
```

but if I use the JMC and JFR provided with the jdk (8_162) itself it works like charme. It is also the same jdk I use for eclipse. The exception idicates that there is some kind of file access problem, so I tried different locations but nothing worked so far.

I also tried to use `...jmxremote.access.file` with the roles explained in the documentation. But still within eclipse it didn't work.

Note: parameter I currently use

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3614 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

All other questions I found so far didn't help me any further so other ideas?

Thanks
Christian

Comment: Did you also pay attention to this one? http://download.oracle.com/technology/products/missioncontrol/updatesites/base/6.0.0/eclipse/run-on-jdk-instructions/index.html

Comment: @howlger yes I did. I do use a jdk as start parameter for eclipse. `-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_162/jre/bin\server\jvm.dll`

Comment: What is it you are trying to do, I guess start a flight recording? Does it matter which JVM you do this on?

Comment: @Klara Yes you are right I try to start flight recorder (JFR right?) and I tried also JDK 8_112 or do you mean another jdk like OpenJDK

Comment: I realize I was not very clear :) What I meant was if it matters if it's a local JVM or a JMX connection. If you try to start JFR against "The JVM Running Eclipse" or whatever the local connection is called, do you get the same problem? Which path do you select for the recording.jfr file?

Comment: @Klara hello, I tried both a `local:3614` and a `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:3614/jmxrmi` connection in both cases the same error occurs. As target folder I tried a `c:\tmp` folder and also the default folder what is a plugin folder within my workspace. In both folders I do have read/write permissions

Answer (score 0):

When you start a recording, the JVM writes a placeholder file where the recording will be written when it is finished.

```
 FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("recording.jfr"); 
 fw.close();
```

The OS is denying the user, the process owner of the Java application you are connecting to, permission to write to that directory. If no path is given, i.e. "recording.jfr", the file will typically end up in the directory where the process was started.